# rspec expect using a then condition

Tags: rspec, rspec3

using the following as an example:

var1, err1 = class.method

here is the pseudo code of what I would like to write a compound rspec expect statement to handle:

If var1 is nil then err1 should not be nil

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `if`s in test code, instead write 2 test cases covering its own variant.

```
  it 'when var1 is nil, err1 is not nil' do
    var1, err1 = some_method('when var1 is nil')

    expect(var1).to be_nil
    expect(err1).not_to be_nil
  end

  it 'when err1 is nil, var1 is not nil' do
    var1, err1 = some_method('when err1 is nil')

    expect(var1).not_to be_nil
    expect(err1).to be_nil
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I was hoping to be able to do compound expects i.e: `expect(light.color).to eq("green").or eq("yellow").or eq("red") '

Comment: Well, they actually work exactly as you write in your comment, details here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/compound-expectations